# Функция передачи данных между двумя прoграммами. std::vector в функции CopyMemory

Tags: c++

Возможно ли передать данные динамического масcива std:vector из одной программы в другую функцией CopyMemory? Так чтобы вторая программа видела и имела доступ к классам и обьектам первой программы. pBuf второй программы показывает размер массива "size 3", но данные обьектов внутри массива пустые, пишет "Unable to read memory".

1 программа:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "myObject.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

typedef std::vector <myObject> Vec;

INT APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd)
{

    HANDLE hMapFile;
    Vec *pBuf;
    Vec pA;
    Vec * pntrA;
    myObject pB;
    myObject pC;
    myObject pD;    

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
        NULL,                    // default security
        PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
        0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
        BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
        szName);                 // name of mapping object

    pBuf = (Vec*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    pC.data[0] = 0.11141112;
    pA.push_back(pC);
    pA.push_back(pB);
    pA.push_back(pD);

    pntrA = &pA;

    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, pntrA, 256);
    _getch();   

    return 0;
}
```

2 программа:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "myObject.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

typedef std::vector <myObject> Vec;

INT APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd)
{
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    Vec *pBuf;

    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
        FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
        szName);               // name of mapping object


    pBuf = (Vec*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Передавать между процессами можно лишь примитивные данные, указатели передавать нельзя (они в чужом адресном пространстве не имеют смысла).

Comment: Нужно что бы две программы работали как одна. Получилось пока только переслать данные типа double. Может возможны какие то другие решения?

Comment: Они имеют смысл для меня:)

Comment: Нет, пользоваться классами одного процесса в другом невозможно, забудьте. Вы можете лишь передавать туда/обратно примитивные или сериализованные данные, и работать с ними в каждом процессе по отдельности.

Comment: Может быть, вам нужно не две программы, а два _потока_?

Comment: Одна программа .exe, а другая dll (будет несколько dll, они будут запускатся и работать внутри другого (третьего) проложения). Dll пользуются классами .exe. Это возможно через потоки?

Comment: Так для этого даже потоки не нужны, просто слинкуйтесь с этой dll и вызывайте её функции

Comment: Тогда Dll будут одновременно использоватся двумя приложениями( я это уже пробовал) Спасибо!  Нужно еще раз попробовать!

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, Вы пытаетесь отобразить в вирутальную память объект, имеющий тип `std::vector <myObject>`. Даже не зная реализации `myObject`, исключительно по наличию `std::vector` можно сказать, что это провальное дело - в реализации вектора не обошлось без указателей, а как уже выше было справедливо замечено [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd):

> указатели передавать нельзя (они в чужом адресном пространстве не имеют смысла)

*Но возможно, мы даже до этого и не дойдем: у нас просто не получится восстановить структуру вектора. Это тоже самое что взять и сериализовать объект класса, который является производным от другого класса - массив байтов мы получим, но как восстановим данные о таблице виртуальных ф-ий, например? Видимо, никак :) Если я ошибаюсь - буду только рад услышать опровергающие вышесказанное факты.*

Comment: Да я заметил, простые данные (такие как double) получается, а как только добавляю объект в std::vector, то данные этого объекта уже не виды. В классе myObject есть std::vector, простые переменные, указатели на объекты, и функции. Если убрать всё что включает указатели, то получится? Я начял использовать std:: vector, потому что нужен был динамический массив, так как количество объектов не известно и их может быть много... Спасибо, теперь всё начинает проясняться.

Comment: @silentsky, я бы сказал так - с любым POD-типом это получится. Даже если это будет массив объектов - но только POD-типа.

Comment: Тогда придется заменить стд:: вектор чем то другим.. Идеально было бы общее адресное пространство для обеих программ.. Также в самой функции CopyMemory  есть сложность, нужно указать размер передаваемых данных в байтах, и размер буфера, если указать неправильно, то программа виснет...

Comment: > бы общее адресное пространство для обеих программ - так точно нельзя, но, я думаю, Вы и сами это понимаете. А что Вам мешает разместить эти элементы на куче, а потом их смапить?

Comment: Мешает нехватка опыта:)